# Change the process virtual address space of a child process

Tags: unix, parent-child, virtual-address-space

I would like to know if it is poosible to change the virtual address space of a child process in Unix like operating system.
I want to have the ability to

(a) Load/unload shared libraries

(b) Write to random user space memory locations of the child process ( not shared memory)

I basically want complete control (think windows 95 like control) over the process address space of a child process.

I know debuggers achieve this to a certain extent, but do you achieve this (system calls to be used, tutorials about subject,etc)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into [ptrace](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/ptrace/).

> ```
>  ptrace() provides tracing and debugging facilities.  It allows one
>  process (the tracing process) to control another (the traced process).
> ```

You can use `PTRACE_ATTACH` to start tracing, `PTRACE_GETREGS` (SETREGS) to get/set registers, `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` (POKEUSER) to read/write user data and `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` (POKEDATA) to read/write data/code sections.